# Copy Cell to another sheet in condition is met Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I need to loop through a column and  if a conditions if met copy  cell from one sheet to another.

I'm finding problems with the incremental..
In this case double the results.

Thank you in advance.
KR

```
Sub copycell()

Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim erow As Long

erow = 1

iLastRow = Worksheets("Clientes").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 13 To iLastRow
    If Sheets("Clientes").Cells(i, 3) = "0" Then
        Worksheets("Ficheros").Range("B" & erow).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheets("Clientes").Cells(i, 4)

        erow = erow + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't normally need a loop for this. Using a filter, and then copying visible cells, is one way to do it in one step.

Comment: If `erow` represents the last row, I'm not sure you need the `End(xlUp).Offset(1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use Autofilter to filter the column C and if the autofilter returns any rows, copy them to the destination sheet?

See if something like this works for you...

```
Sub CopyCells()
Dim wsData As Worksheet, WsDest As Worksheet
Dim iLastRow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wsData = Worksheets("Clientes")
Set WsDest = Worksheets("Ficheros")
iLastRow = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

wsData.AutoFilterMode = False

With wsData.Rows(12)
    .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="0"
    If wsData.Range("D12:D" & iLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
        wsData.Range("D13:D" & iLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        WsDest.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
End With

wsData.AutoFilterMode = False

Application.CutCopyMode = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your result with `AutoFilter`, but my answer is trying to resolve your code using the `For` loop.

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub copycell()

Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim erow As Long

' get first empty row in column B in "Ficheros" sheet
erow = Worksheets("Ficheros").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

With Worksheets("Clientes")
    iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 13 To iLastRow
        If .Cells(i, 3) = "0" Then
            Worksheets("Ficheros").Range("B" & erow) = .Cells(i, 4)

            erow = erow + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```